How do I get video frame buffer stream from a connected GoPro camera?
I'm creating an app that can connect to a GoPro camera and I want to get the frame buffer stream from the connected GoPro camera and use it on my iOS app (by converting the buffer data into CMSampleBuffer). I'm currently trying to use the FFmpeg library but so far it doesn't work. Here's the logic I've implemented (I'm using ChatGPT to generate the code):
import Foundation
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation
import ffmpegkit


final class FFmpegBufferProcessor: AnyBufferProcessor {
    weak var delegate: BufferProcessorDelegate?
    
    private var pipePath: String = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "ffmpeg_pipe"
    private var isProcessing: Bool = false
    private var videoWidth = 1920
    private var videoHeight = 1080
    private let pixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
    
    init() {
        setupPipe()
    }
    
    deinit {
        cleanupPipe()
    }
    
    private func setupPipe() {
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: pipePath) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: pipePath)
            }
            
            let result = mkfifo(pipePath.cString(using: .utf8), 0o644)
            if result != 0 {
                print("\(#function); Pipe creation failed.")
                return
            }
        } catch {
            print("\(#function); Setup pipe error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func cleanupPipe() {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: pipePath)
        } catch {
            print("\(#function); Cleanup pipe error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func startProcessingStream(from udpURL: String) {
        guard !isProcessing else {
            print("\(#function); Already processing stream.")
            return
        }
        
        isProcessing = true
        let command = """
        -i \(udpURL) -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv12 \(pipePath)
        """
        
        FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command) { [weak self] session in
            let returnCode = session?.getReturnCode()
            if ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode) {
                print("\(#function); FFmpeg session completed.")
            } else {
                print("\(#function); FFmpeg session error: \(String(describing: session?.getFailStackTrace())).")
            }
            
            self?.isProcessing = false
        }
        
        readFromPipe()
    }
    
    func stopProcessingStream() {
        isProcessing = false
        FFmpegKit.cancel()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private methods

private extension FFmpegBufferProcessor {
    func readFromPipe() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [unowned self] in
            guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: self.pipePath) else {
                print("\(#function); Fail to read file handle from pipe path.")
                return
            }
            
            autoreleasepool {
                while self.isProcessing {
                    let frameSize = self.videoWidth * self.videoHeight * 3 / 2
                    let rawData = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: frameSize)
                    
                    if rawData.isEmpty {
                        print("\(#function); Pipe closed / no more data to read.")
                        break
                    }
                    
                    self.handleRawFrameData(rawData)
                }
                
                fileHandle.closeFile()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handleRawFrameData(_ data: Data) {
        let width = 1920
        let height = 1080
        
        // Creating the Pixel Buffer (if possible)
        guard let pixelBuffer = createPixelBuffer(from: data, width: width, height: height) else {
            print("\(#function); Failed to create pixel buffer")
            return
        }
        
        var timing = CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30), presentationTimeStamp: .zero, decodeTimeStamp: .invalid)
        // Creating the Sample Buffer (if possible)
        guard let sampleBuffer = createSampleBuffer(from: pixelBuffer, timing: &timing) else {
            print("\(#function); Failed to create sample buffer")
            return
        }
        
        delegate?.bufferProcessor(self, didOutput: sampleBuffer)
    }
}

Here's the logs I'm getting from FFMpeg:

Also a quick note, I'm using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer to enqueue and show the buffers, but obviously it doesn't show up.
What should I do to fix this? Or maybe is there any other way to get the frame buffers from a GoPro camera and show it in iOS? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Better use the OpenGoPro driver.
